# Location of Schema's for Custom Action Executor for Oozie

Tags: oozie, oozie-coordinator

As per the oozie documentation, I can create a Custom Oozie ActionExecutor.

To do this, I need to create a class that extends ActionExecutor. The class needs to be packaged as a Jar. This jar should be placed under the lib directory of oozie server. This part is clear.

However, where should I place the XSD file that defines the Action? Searched in the oozie server locations and I could not find a clue. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Per the [Oozie documentation](https://oozie.apache.org/docs/4.0.0/DG_CustomActionExecutor.html#Deploying_a_custom_Action_Executor):

> The XML schema (XSD) for the new Actions should be added to
>   oozie-site.xml, under the property
>   'oozie.service.WorkflowSchemaService.ext.schemas'. A comma separated
>   list for multiple Action schemas.

Comment: The setting in the site.xml only tells to use the XSD. What Im looking for is , where to place the actual file?

Comment: After scanning through multiple libraries inside the lib folder of oozie server, understood that the .xsd file can be packaged in the same WAR file where the ActionExecutor is packaged. Make sure that the XSD is at the root f the JAR file. Im yet to test the same, but I would assume that this will work

Comment: I don't have a custom action of my own to test, but I would suggest putting it on the local filesystem of the Oozie server host and referencing the full path to the XSD file in the property.